# Breaker tripping for circuit when turning on any switch

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I’ve been suddenly having an issue on one of the circuits in my home. When I flip any light or fan switch, it immediately trips the breaker. I have changed the fan/light in one bedroom and a light in the adjoining room on the same circuit, but that was years before this issue suddenly started happening. I’ve already replaced the breaker which did not fix the problem.

Is there a clever way to isolate where the short is occurring? I know the next step is probably to call an electrician, but I would prefer if I could isolate the problem before doing so. Thanks for any suggestions.

What is perplexing about this issue is sometimes the circuit won’t trip for days or months until it suddenly trips again. Then it trips consistently for a short while.

Edit: right now all lights are turned on on the circuit and it’s not tripping. adding image of breaker/panel
[image: breaker]

Comment: Have you check the switch/s?  Trips usually happen because there is a short, short happens because hot/live wire/screw touches ground/grounded metal.  Since it happens when turning on switch, problem should be at switch, or between switch and light/device.  Some people wrap electric tape around switch so hot screws are protected/insulated.

Comment: Does the breaker involved have a TEST button on it?

Comment: If this is a standard breaker and old school incandescent lamps are involved you may have a lamp that the filament has shorted not a common thing but I have had it happen and been called in to fix this same issue on more than a dozen times , but none lately since 100w bulbs have been eliminated.

Comment: Have you done any *other* work lately?  And we really need to know about that "test" button. Feel free to [edit] to add details.

Comment: Did I read that correctly, in your first paragraph you said turning on "any switch"? More info is needed to help. pics of your panel's breakers would be a good starting point.

Comment: The breaker does ind Ed have a test button. When I flip the breaker on and press test, it instantly trips.

Comment: @ehftwelve -- I take it that when you say "when I flip the breaker on and press test", you mean you're holding the TEST button down when you turn the breaker on?